# yii2 get related records

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2

I am wanting to display posts that a user has liked using the listview widget therefore the dataprovider must contain the correct records as I dont want to be doing any query in my view.

I can access post data using the following in my view:

```
<?php foreach ($likedposts as $post) { ?>
    <?php var_dump($post->likedpost['title']); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

My controller is as follows:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id; 

    $likedposts =  Likedposts::find()->where([ 'user_id' => $user_id])->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'likedposts' => $likedposts,
    ]);
}
```

I want to be able to access data for example like below:

```
<?php foreach ($likedposts as $model) { ?>
    <?php var_dump($model->title); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**Schema**
Users 
-id
-name
-email
-password

Blog Post
-id
-title
-content

Liked Posts
-id
-post_id
-user_id

**UPDATE:**

The below the first variable I need to get all the liked posts however I only really need to select the post_id from the table as it will be used in the dataprovider which will then get all posts which id fall within the likedpost variable(need to create an array of variables maybe?)

```
    $likedposts =  Likedposts::find()->where([ 'user_id' => $user_id])->all();
    $dataProvider = Posts::find()->where(['id'] => $likedposts->post_id])->all();
```

**UPDATE 2(works if only one/single record)**

```
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id; 

    //if i can change ->one() to all() it breaks
    $likedposts =  Likedposts::find()->where([ 'user_id' => $user_id])->one();

    $DataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Posts::find()->
                where(['id' => $likedposts->post_id])->
                orderBy('id DESC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);


    return $this->render('index', [
        'DataProvider' => $DataProvider,
    ]);
```

Error I get if I use all()

Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I want to the list view widget that render a partial however I am unable to use it as it contains the following $model->title where as to get the title using the data I have access to I have to use $post->likedpost['title']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it passing the related models and dataProvider to the view ..

I don't know your code so i can   only do a few suggest in a simbolic manner

```
public function actionIndex()
{

   $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id; 
   $modellUser = User::find()->where(['id'=> $_user])->one();

  $modelBlogPost = BlogPost::find()->where(['user_id' => $user_id])->one();

  $searchModel = new \common\models\LikedpostsSearch();
  $dataProviderLikedposts= $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
  $dataProviderLikedposts->query->andWhere('User  = ' . $User_id );

    return $this->render('index', [
      'modelUser' => $modelUser,
      'modelBlogPost' =$modelBlogPost,
      'dataProviderLikedposts' => $dataProviderLikedposts,
    ]);
}
```

In your view

you can

create a :

```
 detailView with  the $modelUser  for user information

 <?=  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $modelUser,
    'mode' => 'view',
    'attributes' => [
       .....
    ],
 ]) ?>
```

a

```
detailView with the $modelBlogPost for the blog post information

<?=  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $modelBlogPost,
    'mode' => 'view',
    'attributes' => [
       .....
    ],
  ]) ?>
```

a

```
listView with the $dataProvideLikedpost for the likedpost information ..


<?= ListView::widget( [
  'dataProvider' => $dataProviderLikedposts,
  .....
 ] ); ?>
```

I hope this element can suggest you the correct solution
If the problem is only related to obtain a dataProvider like you need

For a dataProvider with your query you should create the query

```
$likedposts =  Likedposts::find()->where([ 'user_id' => $user_id])->all();

// only the query whitout all otherwise you obtain the models not the dataProvider
$query = Posts::find()->where(['id'] => $likedposts->post_id]);
```

create the new dataProvider with your query

```
 $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
 'query' => $query,
'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 20,
],
```

]);

and then pass this `'dataProvider' => $provider` in you render view

**Update for all()**

I think the last comment (work with one() and not with all() is related to the fact that the result in $likedposts is a collection of models. In this case likedposts->post_id don't contain an array of post_id  but is a non object (the object would be   $likedposts['0']->post_id)..

In your query you need a vector/array containing the set of post_id  liked by user.

```
foreach ($likedposts as $key => $value) { 
    myArray[] = $value;
}


$query = Posts::find()->where( 'id IN ' . $myArray);

or 

$query = Posts::find()->where(['id'] => $myArray]);
```

Comment: Still struggling it difficult to describe by problem but i have updated the question which might help you see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Well in your update you getting models not dataProvider.. if you want get the dataprovider  you need a dataProvider with your query... ten minutes and i update the answer..

Comment: When it get to the query line I get the following error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: seems your $likedposts don't get result...and then not valid result $likedpost->post_id   check for a proper result of $likedposts...

Comment: I have updated my question with some progress I know its not ideal and should probably be moved to my model however I am just trying to get it working.